# How to include excerpt in ul from different pages with the same parent - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I wish to get the title, the excerpt and some meta from three different pages that all have the same parent.

I do not wish to specify wich three pages to show but rather show the three that was last edited/published.

I aim to display the content as three blocks on a horizontal line.

As I was unable to get the code to work:

```
<ul id="">
<?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&post_parent=4"); the_post(); ?>
<li>
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "image", true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</li>
</ul>
```

---

Thank you Dan, this still does not work though. The excrept of the first page does not show (the title shows and the meta also). Tried the code below with the same result except that the second time the content is displayed, the excerpt of the first page shows.

```
<?php get_header(); the_post(); ?>
<div id="main-content">
<?php
$categoriesCF = get_post_meta($post->ID, "categories", true);
$allCategories = explode(",", $categoriesCF);
foreach ($allCategories as $category) {
$pieces = explode("|", $category);
$link = get_permalink($pieces[1]);
echo "<div class='product-group group'>";
echo "<h3><a href='$link'>" . $pieces[0] . "</a></h3>";
query_posts("posts_per_page=-1&post_type=page&post_parent=$pieces[1]");
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="product-jump" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-large="<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, "image", true); ?>">
<?php echo "<img src='" . get_post_meta($post->ID, "image", true) . "' />"; ?>
<span class="product-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
<span class="product-title"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span></a>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();
echo "</div>";
};
?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `posts_per_page` to 3 and use `orderby=date&order=DESC` to get the 3 most recent.

If you are displaying this on a page that already shows some other post/page/posts/pages, use `get_posts` instead of `query_posts`.

The WordPress codex has full documentation and examples for all of these things:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Comment: You need a loop. Look at the linked pages' example code. Don't just copy and paste your code 3 times.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I have edited the code as shown in the question. The code works execpt that the excerpt from the first page does not show (the title and meta of the first page shows though) until the second part. Then it shows.